# Creating a bad outcome as a bookie?

Tags: probability, logic, gambling

I found this question from [Ian Hacking's book on induction and probability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521775019). I understand that a Dutch Book is a gambling term wherein every outcome results in the bookie (us) winning. Although, the last part of the question 'Describe a Dutch Book for Paolo' is confusing. How is this prediction one where everyone wins?

> Paolo has fallen for the famous “bank-teller” fallacy. His personal
>   degree of confidence that Sara is a bank teller is $\dfrac15$, but his
>   personal degree of confidence that she’s a feminist bank-teller is
>   $\dfrac14.$ Describe a Dutch Book for Paolo.

Comment: Sit down with Paolo and say, "Let me tell you about _The Diary of a Young Girl_ ..."

Comment: you can see what Paolo has wrong, if she is a feminist bank-teller (his credence of that 1/4) then she is a bank teller, for which he assigns a 1/5 probability, which is less probability than for the more restrictive case - other than that - I can't really help - your question seems to 'lack context' there is a tips page somewhere on how to improve questions

Comment: @Cato I'm afraid that's the exact question. There is no more context in the book itself, other than explanation of personal bets and conditionals.

Comment: @andrew - thanks for the explanation!  I've never heard the bank teller fallacy, so it's given me something to read anyway - I'm presuming it wants you to state bookies odds for the events based on what paolo will bet